# iPhone app downloaded from HockeyApp is not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, hockeyapp

I am using HockeyApp as a beta testing tool. For the iOS build, all the correct certificates and signing identities were used, however when I download the App on an iPhone X, it says "Waiting" which is to be expected and then when it gets close to finishing the download, it seems to stop and the following happens:

1. The App icon isn't displayed
2. It shows the HockeyApp title instead of the App name
3. The icon is not clickable. ie. the App doesn't open at all. It does not crash upon opening, it just doesn't open.

My Build settings are as follows:

1. SDK Version: Default
2. Linker Behavior: Link Framework SDK's only
3. Supported architecture: ARM64

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: UDID of device is added on profile in which you're installing

Comment: I've checked this and the UDID is there

Comment: did you trust the developer in system settings?

Comment: @BencePattogato, yes I have

Comment: Please inspect the device console logs to get a proper error message of what is going wrong during the installation process.

Comment: The problem was in the Entitlements.plist. Push notifications was ticked when there was no certificate for it. Made the build succeed but the install fail